# Laravel Filament adding data to multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I need to add data to more than one table with belongsToMany in the project I developed with Laravel filament.

Example DB:

- Category: id, name
- Anime: id, name, description
- AnimeCategory: id, category_id, anime_id

Code:

- Anime Resource: https://codeshare.io/3AEg7v
- Anime Model: https://codeshare.io/mpydBj
- Category Model: https://codeshare.io/lorKBD
- AnimeCategory Model: https://codeshare.io/r9A3BY

I am getting categoryId not found error in Anime Table.

Found in Anime Resource:

```
Select::make('categoryId')
    ->label('Kategori seçiniz')
    ->placeholder('Kategori Seçiniz')
    ->required()
    ->multiple()
    ->options(function () {
        return Category::all()->pluck('title', 'id');
    }),
```

How can I add selected multi-category id data to AnimeCategory table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

Anime Model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'anime_categories', 'animeId', 'categoryId');
}
```

Anime Resource CategoryId Multiple Select

```
Select::make('categoryId')
    ->relationship('categories', 'title')
    ->label('Kategori seçiniz')
    ->placeholder('Kategori Seçiniz')
    ->required()
    ->multiple()
    ->preload()
```